# Pass a JavaScript variable to a shiny app contained in a iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, shiny

I have a website with a DataTable. Following [this](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html) I create a js event on clicking on a row. The event stores an id corresponding to the clicked row in a variable and following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25098153/1707938) I posted a message to the `shiny-iframe`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
"columnDefs": [
            {
                "targets": [ 0 ],
                "visible": false,
                "searchable": false
            }
            ]
});
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var data  = table.row( this ).data();
        var table_row_id = data[0];
        var frame = document.getElementById('shiny-iframe');
        frame.contentWindow.postMessage(table_row_id, '*');
    } );
} );
```

Still I am not sure how to proceed from here. The end result is to have shiny reloading the app in the iframe with as argument the variable stored in `table_row_id`.

Comment: Here is the way to pass JS variables to Shiny https://ryouready.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/sending-data-from-client-to-server-and-back-using-shiny/